# How do i implement bubblesort and where

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

The task is to implement a bubblesort function followed by a linearsearch aka "linsok" in my "familj" array. the array keeps both the name and the age, so i want to sort the array after their age and print it out. ive got the line search to work but now im stuck with the bubblesort.

The problem is that i dont know how to make my bubble sort code work for this code.
so do i implement the second piece of code in this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



class Person        
{
    public:
    string namn;    
    int alder;

    void skrivUt(string _namn, int _alder)  
    {
        namn = _namn;
        alder = _alder;
    }
};

int linsok(Person* PersonArray, int key) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
    if (PersonArray[i].alder == key)
        return i;
    }
return -1;
}


int main()
{

    Person familj[4];               
    familj[1].skrivUt("Emma",23);
    familj[3].skrivUt("Emilia",29);
    familj[2].skrivUt("Johan",26);
    familj[0].skrivUt("Timmy ",21);


int index = linsok(familj,22);  //the age of the person im looking for.


if(index== -1)                      
    cout << "Personen hittades ej!"; //person not found
else            
         //prints out the persons name and the index.                   
    cout << "Personen heter " << familj[index].namn << " hen finns på index " << index << endl;


cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

This is the piece of bubble-sort code i used before and it works.

```
int p [] = {10,56,73,23,31,24,43};  
int a = 6;


for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    int nrLeft = a - i;
    for (int j = 0; j < nrLeft; j++)
    {
        if (p[j] > p[j+1])
        {
            int temp = p[j];
            p[j] = p[j+1];
            p[j+ 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
cout << p[i] << endl;  
cin.get();
```

Comment: if this is not a school assignment or pure learning exercise, use `std::sort` instead

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for sharing your story. You've presented your task, but you have not explained which part of your task you are having trouble with. Edit your question to provide those details. Remember to review your lecture notes and your textbook, where you have already learned how bubble sort works.

Comment: Bubble sort is a very simple algorithm. You can easily search online for examples you can check your code against.

Comment: [Hi, have a read of this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and remember that you need to *specifically* detail the problem that you're having.

Comment: This is a school assignment, so i have to use it. My problem is that i dont understand how i can implement my bubble sort code in the main code. ive tried but failed

Comment: @Timmyssj Okay, are you having a problem writing a bubble sort, or are you having trouble integrating a bubble sort with your program, or getting an incorrect result? You need to explicitly state that in your question, so you should edit it in.

Comment: @Timmyssj I don't know if my answer was helpful or not, but on the offchance that it was, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the tick next to it. Also, since you're new here, have a quick read of [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). It'll give you an idea of how the site works, as it's a bit different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you want to convert this to a function that you pass your array of `Person` objects to, along with the size of it, and then you just access the part that you want to compare. Since you'd be implementing it as a function, you can use it in the same way you use your `linsok` function, although you'd probably want it to return the sorted array as opposed to an index.
*Disclaimer for following code: Neither run nor compiled*

```
Person* bubbleSort(Person* p, int size)
{
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    int nrLeft = size - i;
    for (int j = 0; j < nrLeft; j++)
    {
        if (p[j].alder > p[j+1].alder)
        {
            Person temp = p[j];
            p[j] = p[j+1];
            p[j+ 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
return p;
}
```

That's based off you sorting them by alder (which I guess is age? I don't speak Swedish(?)) You just need to provide the signature, and alter it based on your needs, but the basic idea is that you just change what you compare, and the data types.

Another way to do this is to return an `int` or `void`(But you should return an int to tell you if it was successful or not), and pass a pointer to the array, so `Person**` in the signature, and operate directly on that array, but that's a little more difficult, and arguably bad practice, depending on use case.